# Find the angle and the axis between to rotations using quaternions

Tags: c++, quaternions, glm-math

I start with a 45° tilted vector. Later, I tilt it around another axis by 45°. How can I find out how much the vector was tilted and around which axis? I thought using the inverse of the starting quaternion would be enough.

Code:

```
glm::quat beg = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(45.f), glm::vec3(1, 1, 0));
glm::vec3 eul = glm::degrees(glm::eulerAngles(beg));
qDebug() << "eul:" << eul[0] << eul[1] << eul[2];

glm::quat end = beg * glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(45.f), glm::vec3(1, 1, 0));
eul = glm::degrees(glm::eulerAngles(end));
qDebug() << "end:" << eul[0] << eul[1] << eul[2];
```

Question begins here, I would like to get e.g. 45° around (1,1,0).

```
glm::quat dif = end * glm::inverse(beg);
eul = glm::degrees(glm::eulerAngles(dif));
qDebug() << "dif:" << eul[0] << eul[1] << eul[2];
```

Out:

```
eul: 51.5893 45 18.9394
end: 130.852 52.4567 72.55
dif: 51.5893 45 18.9394
```